# Sort by each columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table

```
DPN      Incidents  wk32        wk31             wk30            wk29
15326868    2.00    16,020.98   9,586.14        
13655518    2.00    15,246.40   2,619.89        
13592065    4.00    4,138.67    7,851.41    7,725.56          7,593.11
13968309    4.00    3,027.89    3,788.18    10,155.71         2,328.68
13533086    4.00    10,266.52   6,479.47    8,761.08         10,949.50
13838079    3.00    5,890.04    1,214.42                     10,445.45
```

If they enter a topx=2

I should have the output as

```
DPN # of Incidents  wk32               wk31     wk30             wk29
15326868    2.00    16,020.98       9,586.14        
13655518    1.00    15,246.40           
13592065    1.00                    7,851.41                 
13968309    1.00                              10,155.71        
13533086    2.00                              8,761.08       10,949.50      
13838079    1.00                                             10,445.45
```

The above output is it should sort each week by desc and display in the same format as above and Also recalculate no of incidents.
Incidents is how many columns the value is present for each.
Pls let me know how to do that.

Comment: Ok, to explain it somehow... when enter topx 2, means show top two weekly values and make the rest empty.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind: Yes, we need to sort each week desc and display top two DPN's for each week.

Comment: -1 : Nice Question. But Downvoted, show your effort first.

Comment: @Roms: I tried at my end. Since I couldnt get the output I asked here. Not sure I need to write the query what i did. So i ve nt put. Anywas thanks for you vote:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few pieces to this.  The first is using `row_number()` to identify the top two in each week.  The second is limiting the values to those two, and the third is re-calculating `incidents`:

```
select DPN,
       sum((case when wk32 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when wk31 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when wk30 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
           (case when wk29 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
          ) as incidents,
       wk32, wk31, wk30, wk29
from (select DPN,
             (case when seqnum_wk32 <= 2 then wk32 end) as wk32,
             (case when seqnum_wk31 <= 2 then wk32 end) as wk31,
             (case when seqnum_wk30 <= 2 then wk32 end) as wk30,
             (case when seqnum_wk29 <= 2 then wk32 end) as wk29
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by wk32 desc) as seqnum_wk32,
                   row_number() over (order by wk31 desc) as seqnum_wk31,
                   row_number() over (order by wk30 desc) as seqnum_wk30,
                   row_number() over (order by wk29 desc) as seqnum_wk29
           from t
          ) t
     ) t
order by wk32 desc, wk31 desc, wk30 desc, wk29 desc;
```